# How can I prevent the current tab view from being lost when rotating the screen?

Tags: android

I have tabhost with 4 tabs. If I (for example) open tab #3, start a simple alert dialog, and then rotate the phone a few times, it loses focus on which tab was open before, so when I press back, tab #1 shows up instead of tab #3.

I would be **very** grateful for a solution or any hints to solve this problem.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {   
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getTabHost().setCurrentTab(currentTab);
    }   
    private void saveState(){
        currentTab=getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try save state of TabHost? If not - check Reto Meier answer in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state).

You can save current position of TabHost using getCurrentTab at onSaveInstanceState, and restore it at onRestoreInstanceState using setCurrentTab.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I updated what I tried (that does not work).